# I keep getting an error when I try to pass the head pointer of the linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, linked-list

I keep getting an error saying `undefined symbol insert(*Friend)`. Can anyone identif and explain the error please? I know it refers to the fact that it cannot find it but I can't identify what is wrong please helppp. I am working on a program that keeps a database of friends' information using a linked-list. Therefore, I am trying to initialize the head node to `null` once the program starts and check for the first insert if this head is `null`, if that's the case assign the pointer to the new node.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// MARK: Friend Struct

struct Friend {

    string last;
    string first;
    int yob;
    int mob;
    int dob;
    string sex;
    struct Friend* next;
};

Friend* head = NULL;
void insert(struct Friend* head);
void getData();

// MARK: Main Method
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    insert(head);

    return 0;
}

// MARK: Get Data Method

void getData(string& f, string& l, string& s, int& y, int& m, int& d)
{

    cout << "Please type friend's first name: " << endl;
    cin >> f;
    cout << "Please type friend's last name: " << endl;
    cin >> l;
    cout << "Please type friend's year of birth (yyyy): " << endl;
    cin >> y;
    cout << "Please type friend's month of birth (mm): " << endl;
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Please type friend's day of birth (dd): " << endl;
    cin >> d;
    cout << "Please type friend's sex (f/m): " << endl;
    cin >> s;
}

// MARK: Insert new Friend Method

void insert(struct Friend** head)
{
    string f, l, s;
    int y = 0, m = 0, d = 0;
    getData(f, l, s, y, m, d);

    Friend* tmp = new Friend;
    tmp->first = f;
    tmp->last = l;
    tmp->yob = y;
    tmp->mob = m;
    tmp->dob = d;
    tmp->sex = s;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = tmp;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `void insert(struct Friend* head);` (there is only one star), but only defined `void insert(struct Friend** head)` (there are two stars). They are different functions.

It seems the declaration should be corrected to two stars (match to the definition) and `&head` should be passed instead of `head` on calling that.

Answer (score 0):

You passing (Friend*)`head` in `insert(Friend **head)` which is not correct.
Change the call to `insert(&head);`.